# Load custom block with template file with PHP

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a simple module, now I try to load the block with:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('creation_newproducts/newproducts')->setTemplate('newproducts/newproduct.phtml')->toHtml();
```

I can echo content from block function however template file is not loaded.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Creation_Newproducts>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Creation_Newproducts>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <creation_newproducts>
                    <class>Creation_Newproducts_Block_Newproducts</class>
                </creation_newproducts>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Template file:

```
app/design/frontend/default/mt_colinus/template/newproducts/newproducts.phtml
```

[image]

How can i echo the template file?

Is this even possible outside controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make change in your xml file. I have changed following

> Creation_Newproducts_Block_Newproducts **>**
>   Creation_Newproducts_Block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Creation_Newproducts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Creation_Newproducts>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <creation_newproducts>
                <class>Creation_Newproducts_Block</class>
            </creation_newproducts>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then use following code in template

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('creation_newproducts/newproducts')->setTemplate('newproducts/newproducts.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Change file path to same as following. You have not put that file on proper place.

```
app/design/frontend/default/mt_colinus/template/newproducts/newproducts.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks now the creation_newproducts/newproducts works fine, however template file still not loaded.

Comment: Can you please put  `newproduct.phtml` file path?

Comment: Done! see my question!

Comment: Its not fixed!!!

Comment: Check updated answer. You file path is wrong.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, sorry

Comment: Did you cleared cache from admin?

Comment: Yeah cache is disabled and flushed to be sure!

Comment: What is your `.phtml` file name ? Please verify

Comment: Check question.

Comment: Check `setTemplate` function you have typo in file name. Please fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('creation_newproducts/newproducts')->setTemplate('newproducts/newproduct.phtml')->toHtml();
```

creation/newproducts :

creation is your module group name

newproducts is your block class name

Comment: That will only work if blocks have been declared in the `config.xml`

Comment: Hi, I tried that, I copied the code from a module i wrote before only difference is that the block was used in a controller now its in a template file, i believe namespace is also allowed for block declaration and block works, just the template is not loaded, thx!

Comment: update code check it

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/vandonzel/vandonzel.nl/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/mt_colinus/template/page/home.phtml on line 187